# Python Dask: Searching for a value in a column and get the value of a different column

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
                   'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
                   'C': np.arange(8), 'D': np.arange(8) * 2})
```

Just imagine this dataframe now with pandas it is easy for me to find a column based on another column's value just like this:

```
df.loc[df["B"] == "three", "A"]
```

but with dask the output i receive if i use the same code doesn't really help me

```
df.loc[df["ActionGeo_Lat"] == "42#.5", "SQLDATE"]
```

after executing this line i receive the following output, which doesn't really help me:

[image: Output after executing my code]

The problem i'm having is that everytime i try to execute `df.compute` i receive

> ValueError:ValueError: could not convert string to float: '42#.5'.

After cutting out some columns i found out that the error is caused somewhere in the column `ActionGeo_Lat`, now i would like to manually edit the csv file to resolve the error, but cannot find out on which date the error occurs.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your underlying problem is with the loading/typing of your data. Here's an example that shows that the same `pandas` syntax works without problems on the `dask` dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
                   'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
                   'C': np.arange(8), 'D': np.arange(8) * 2})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

print(df.loc[df['B'] == "three", "A"])
print(ddf.loc[ddf['B'] == "three", "A"].compute())
```

`dask.dataframe` is not a good way to debug csv files, so best way for you is to use `shell/bash` utilities for editing files, e.g.

```sh
grep -ai "42#.5" your_file_name_here.csv
```

Comment: OP: "Thanks grep worked for me, I was able to grep over all my csv files and found the wrong string"

Comment: Great that it worked for you, @Paul Bruder! (thanks for the commenting: @HashRocketSyntax)